# How does attunement work?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

I would like to use the *[Gauntlets of Ogre Power](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gauntlets%20of%20Ogre%20Power#content)*, which states that the item "requires attunement".

What am I supposed to attune it with?
What are the requisites/requirements?

Comment: Related: [Are there restrictions on who can attune to magical items with no prerequisite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101025/are-there-restrictions-on-who-can-attune-to-magical-items-with-no-prerequisite)

Comment: Thanks V2Blast, that link was actually very useful :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Anyone can attune to the Gauntlets of Ogre Power

You can read up on attunement in the [freely available basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement).

Here are a few of the most relevant excerpts:

> Some magic items require a creature to form a bond with them before their magical properties can be used. This bond is called attunement[...]
>
> Without becoming attuned to an item that requires attunement, a creature gains only its nonmagical benefits, unless its description states otherwise.

So, you can wear them as normal gauntlets fine without attuning - but you you won't get boosted strength until you do attune to them.

> Attuning to an item requires a creature to spend a short rest focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it[...]

So when you ask 'What am I supposed to attune it with?', the answer is that nothing extra is needed - just you, your item and and bit of quality time.

> An item can be attuned to only one creature at a time, and a creature can be attuned to no more than three magic items at a time.

Attunement prevents one character having too many powerful magic items - as any given character cannot attune to more than three at a time.

**Some items do have prerequisites - the gauntlets do not.**

The [gauntlets' rules text](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gauntlets-of-ogre-power) states 'Wondrous item, uncommon (requires attunement)'. So they don't require any prerequisite, beyond having a free attunement slot - and even if you don't have an empty slot you can simply un-attune to one of your previously attuned items and free the slot up for the gauntlets.

An item that did have a prerequisite, such as a [Pearl of Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/pearl-of-power), would state that requirement explicitly. For instance, the Pearl's rules text states 'Wondrous item, uncommon (requires attunement by a spellcaster)'.

**That said, wearable items do have a sort of hidden prerequisite**, unrelated to attunement - [they must be worn as intended](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems):

> Using a magic item's properties might mean wearing or wielding it. A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger. Magic armor must be donned, a shield strapped to the arm, a cloak fastened about the shoulders. A weapon must be held.

That means that **someone without hands could not use the Gauntlets of Ogre Power**. You wouldn't gain the benefit, if for instance, you wore them, somewhat clumsily, on a string round your neck. Sadly even a one armed character would be unable to use them - [they must always be worn in a pair](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#PairedItems).