# Can a tamed owl cast spells from Ring of spell storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ability-scores, animals, attunement

In a campaign I'm currently in, I want to give my owl that I tamed (the DM allows taming wild animals) a *ring of spell storing* so it can cast spells. However, before I do so, I wanted to ask:

Is there anything mentioned about needing a high enough Int to attune or use magic items? Or can you use them no matter how low your Int is?

From what I can find, it seems to only require that the creature spends a short rest focused on the item, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Related: [Are there restrictions on who can attune to magical items with no prerequisite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101025/are-there-restrictions-on-who-can-attune-to-magical-items-with-no-prerequisite)

Comment: I opened [a Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11305) to discuss the duplicate status of this question (and others). Discussion on the closure/reopening of this question should happen there

Comment: Between the 2 of those it answered my question. Thanks for the help