# Can an animal cast spells via a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, animal-companions

Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178162/38834), (answered [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115569/38834)), I have a follow up question:

### Can a normal animal cast spells via a Ring of Spell Storing?

It seems that any animal, if properly trained, can attune to the Ring. But do they have the ability to cast spells stored within?

This is strictly about trained, wild animals; not familiars where there is a telepathic link, not Beast Master beasts where there is a deeper connection. This is referring to the pig I grew up with, the owl I nursed back to health, or the rat I bought from the local store.

The best I could find so far is the [Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) spell which states:

> ...  the creature's **Intelligence** and Charisma scores **become 1**. The creature **can't cast spells**, activate magic items, understand language, or communicate in any intelligible way. The creature can, however, identify its friends, follow them, and even protect them.

But is the ability score or 1 what prevents the spell casting, or an effect from the spell?

But if we take an owl, it has an Int of 2. Is that enough to cast a spell?

Consider that a PC can still become a Wizard even with the lowest die roll of 3. They just can't multiclass.

Also, from the Ring's [description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing):

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, **but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell**. The spell cast from the ring is no longer stored in it, freeing up space.

There is no mention of whether components are required or not. If they are, could a beast form the words/sounds needed for Verbal components?

Comment: Do you expect answers to assume that the owl can, in fact, attune to the ring?

Comment: @MarkWells, yes. That's why I linked the questions I did--Assuming they are correct and an animal can attune, can they actually use the Ring?

Comment: Related: "[Is there a minimum intelligence score needed to make use of non-natural abilities?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/173790)"

Comment: I have asked to reopen as the "duplicate" question is specifically referring to familiars, and even to Pact of the Chain familiars. I am asking about normal, everyday animals off the street. I have added a not to that affect.

Comment: Is there a reason you think that the answer would be different for a trained, wild animal than for a familiar though? You state *"not familiars where there is a telepathic link, not Beast Master beasts where there is a deeper connection"* but there's nothing in the duplicate question's answer that would suggest that makes any difference. In other words, why doesn't the duplicate answer your question? It seems like the same answer would apply for a wild animal as it would a familiar.

Comment: I opened [a Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11305) to discuss the duplicate status of this question (and others). Discussion on the closure/reopening of this question should happen there

Answer (score 0):

### Animals can cast a spell stored via a Ring of Spell Storing.

Animals are creatures, some of them are listed in the MM [Appendix A: Miscellaneous Creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/miscellaneous-creatures), emphasis mine:

> This appendix contains statistics for various animals, vermin, and
> other critters. The stat blocks are organized alphabetically by
> ***creature*** name.

[Attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement):

> Some magic items require a creature to form a bond with them before
> their magical properties can be used.

Only wearing the ring while attuned is required to cast a spell stored in the [Ring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing):

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it.

This is all of the relevant information, after attuning merely wearing the ring is required for the animal to cast a spell stored in the ring.

How feasible it is for a particular creature to attune is up to the dm.